# GetCountries from .NET not delivering all countries?

Tags: asp.net, .net, globalization

When I use the following code (which used to work fine) I now get, with .NET 4.6, a list that does not include Namibia and includes Yabuuti about 50 times before filtering. Any idea why or what has changed?

```
    private void SetCountriesComboBox()
    {
        RegionInfo country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("en-US", false).LCID);
        List countryNames = new List();
        foreach (CultureInfo cul in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        {
            country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo(cul.Name, false).LCID);
            countryNames.Add(country.DisplayName.ToString());
        }
        IEnumerable nameAdded = countryNames.OrderBy(names => names).Distinct();
        foreach (string item in nameAdded)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RegionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx) returns information on **cultures**, not countries. There is no inbuilt method to return countries (as they have the ability to change infrequently)

Comment: Thanks.. Yes ... and I was using it anyway to generate the countries list as documented by several other posts. I assumed, apparently wrongly, that .NET also intended it for this use since, as you point out, there is no way to directly get the list of countries... The list changes faster than one would imagine...

Answer (score 0):

Many `RegionInfo` are connected to multiple `CultureInfo`. See for example https://ideone.com/yTfO8A . The `RegionInfo` of *India* for example has like 14 `CultureInfo`. The `RegionInfo` of *Switzerland* has 4 `CultureInfo`.

Note that your code is redundant: you rebuild the `new CultureInfo(cul.Name, false).LCID`. Something more sane would be something like:

```
private static void SetCountriesComboBox()
{
    List<string> countryNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (CultureInfo cul in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
    {
        RegionInfo country = new RegionInfo(cul.LCID);
        countryNames.Add(string.Format("{0} ({1})", country.DisplayName, cul.DisplayName));
        // countryNames.Add(country.DisplayName);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> nameAdded = countryNames.OrderBy(names => names).Distinct();

    foreach (string item in nameAdded)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes ... still does not produce the desired result.

Comment: The whole code could be a one-liner: `comboBox1.Items.Add(CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(c => (new RegionInfo(c.LCID)).DisplayName).Distinct().OrderBy(c=>c));`

Comment: @Rik You would need the `AddRange`... But `AddRange` requires and array, so `OrderBy(...).ToArray()`